# Get model out of scikit

Tags: python, model, scikit-learn, formula

I am working on a scientific paper on a predictionmodel predicting complications in major abdominal resections. 
I have been using scikit to create that model and got good results (score of 0.94). This makes us want to see what the model is like that is made by scikit.

As for now we got 100 input variables but logically these arent all as usefull as the others and we want to reduce this number to about 20 and see what the effects on the score are.

**My question**: Is there a way to get the underlying formula for the model out of scikit instead of having it as a 'blackbox' in my svm function.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree, svm, linear_model, metrics, preprocessing
import datetime
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score, ShuffleSplit, GridSearchCV
from time import gmtime, strftime

#database openen en voorbereiden
file = "/home/wouter/scikit/DB_SCIKIT.csv"
DB = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";", header=0, decimal= ',').as_matrix()
DBT = DB
print "Vorm van de DB: ", DB.shape
target = []
for i in range(len(DB[:,-1])):
        target.append(DB[i,-1])
DB = delete(DB,s_[-1],1) #Laatste kolom verwijderen
AantalOutcome = target.count(1)
print "Aantal outcome:", AantalOutcome
print "Aantal patienten:", len(target)

A = DB
b = target

print len(DBT)

svc=svm.SVC(kernel='linear', cache_size=500, probability=True)
indices = np.random.permutation(len(DBT))

rs = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=.15, random_state=None)
scores = cross_val_score(svc, A, b, cv=rs)
A = ("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
print A

X_train = DBT[indices[:-302]]
y_train = []
for i in range(len(X_train[:,-1])):
        y_train.append(X_train[i,-1])
X_train = delete(X_train,s_[-1],1) #Laatste kolom verwijderen

X_test = DBT[indices[-302:]]
y_test = []
for i in range(len(X_test[:,-1])):
        y_test.append(X_test[i,-1])
X_test = delete(X_test,s_[-1],1) #Laatste kolom verwijderen

model = svc.fit(X_train,y_train)
print model

uitkomst = model.score(X_test, y_test)
print uitkomst

voorspel = model.predict(X_test)
print voorspel
```

The output i get from this:

```
Vorm van de DB:  (2011, 101)
Aantal outcome: 128
Aantal patienten: 2011
2011
Accuracy: 0.94 (+/- 0.01)
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=500, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='linear',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
0.927152317881
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Comment: SVM - Support Vector Machine. This is a widely used and known concept, however it's very mathematical - probably will get you some time to get through it.
Just google, there are plenty resources explaining how a SVM works - but just too much for SO.

Comment: Scikit-learn uses the `libsvm` library internally for SVC. So you need to understand that part. You are probably better off using some other feature-selection techniques to decrease the features. Also, since this is about algorithm and not programming, its suitable for https://stats.stackexchange.com, not here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some Feature selection first~
And then use scikit based on the processed data~

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#

(there are 3 ways for Feature selection:filter;wrapper;embedding)